# Object.values not returning a array

Tags: javascript

I am using the fetch api to fetch some data from my own back-end api. As I know fetch gives us a response we must convert it into a json to read the body of the response.The resulting data is in form of json.

```
    fetch(`/user/getFriends?steam64=${dataObj.persondata.steamid}`,{
    method:"GET",
  })
   .then(res=> res.json())
   .then((data)=>{
     const obj = JSON.parse(data);
     const objValues = Object.values(obj);
     console.log(typeof objKeys); //object
   });
```

As we can see in  the code above.I am converting the json back to object by using JSON.parse and storing it into a variable called 'obj'.Then I am using Object.values();
To extract the values from the object and store it in an array.

But if I check the type of 'objValues' it returns **object** rather than **array**.
Please help me out.Any help regarding this is greatly appriciated.THANK YOU

Comment: `JSON.parse(data);`? Should already an be an object after `res.json()`, why are you parsing it?

Comment: You have a typo? You `objValues` and then on the next line you have `objKeys`.

Comment: "*if I check the type of 'objValues' it returns object rather than array*" because `typeof` can only report `"object"` - arrays *are* objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always returns "object" for an array.

```js
console.log(typeof []);
console.log(typeof [1,2,3]);
```

Use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if an object is an array.

```js
console.log(Array.isArray([])); //true
console.log(Array.isArray([1,2,3])); //true
console.log(Array.isArray({})); //false
```